# Why does Example app using Photos framework use stopCachingImagesForAllAssets after each change?

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

So I'm looking at the Photos API and Apple's sample code here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html
and its conversion to swift here
https://github.com/ooper-shlab/SamplePhotosApp-Swift

I have integrated the code into my project so that a collectionView is successfully updating itself form the library as I take photos. There is one quirk: Sometimes cells are blank, and it seems to be connected to stopCachingImagesForAllAssets which Apple calls each time the library is updated at the end of photoLibraryDidChange delegate method.

I can remove the line and it fixes the problem, but surely there is a reason Apple put it there in the first place? I am concerned with memory usage.

```
 // MARK: - PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver

func photoLibraryDidChange(changeInstance: PHChange) {
    // Check if there are changes to the assets we are showing.
    guard let
        assetsFetchResults = self.assetsFetchResults,
        collectionChanges = changeInstance.changeDetailsForFetchResult(assetsFetchResults)
        else {return}

    /*
    Change notifications may be made on a background queue. Re-dispatch to the
    main queue before acting on the change as we'll be updating the UI.
    */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Get the new fetch result.
        self.assetsFetchResults = collectionChanges.fetchResultAfterChanges

        let collectionView = self.pictureCollectionView!

        if !collectionChanges.hasIncrementalChanges || collectionChanges.hasMoves {
            // Reload the collection view if the incremental diffs are not available
            collectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            /*
            Tell the collection view to animate insertions and deletions if we
            have incremental diffs.
            */
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                if let removedIndexes = collectionChanges.removedIndexes
                    where removedIndexes.count > 0 {
                        collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(removedIndexes.aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection(0))
                }

                if let insertedIndexes = collectionChanges.insertedIndexes
                    where insertedIndexes.count > 0 {
                        collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexes.aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection(0))
                }

                if let changedIndexes = collectionChanges.changedIndexes
                    where changedIndexes.count > 0 {
                        collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(changedIndexes.aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection(0))
                }
                }, completion:  nil)
        }

        self.resetCachedAssets() //perhaps prevents memory warning but causes the empty cells
    }
}

//MARK: - Asset Caching

private func resetCachedAssets() {
    self.imageManager?.stopCachingImagesForAllAssets()
    self.previousPreheatRect = CGRectZero
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same result.
Here's what fixed the issue for me:

Since `performBatchUpdates` is asynchronous, the `resetCachedAssets` gets executed possibly while the delete/insert/reload is happening, or even between those.

That didn't sound nice to me. So I moved the line:

```
self.resetCachedAssets()
```

to the first line of the `dispatch_async` block.

I hope this helps you too.

Comment: Oh interesting. Hmm, thinking along what you mentioned about performBatchUpdates being asynchronous, would we actually want to put the self.resetCachedAssets() in the completion handler for performBatchUpdates rather than leave it nil? Then I imagine it would need to get called in the other part of the if statement as well though